# How to run geth without console?

Tags: ethereum, geth

I need run geth on server without console. How to do this? just not add argument console?

And can I attach to geth running without console, when I want to stop geth, or open console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you append an '&' at the end of your `geth <args> &` command, it will run the command as a separate process in the background. Then you should be able to connect to it with `geth attach` from a separate console to stop or modify it.